# SQLite.Net.Async.AsyncTableQuery<T> cannot implicitly convert to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

We have a Xamarin Forms app that's using SQLite to store some table data. We're using the NuGet package sqlite-net-pcl version 1.3.1. The query looks like:

```
SqlLiteAsyncConnection database = DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseUtility>().GetDbConnection();
var result = database.Table<MyTable>();
List<MyTable> records = await result.ToListAsync();
```

When we hit that last line (`result.ToListAsync()`) we get an exception:

```
Cannot implicitly convert SQLite.Net.Async.AsyncTableQuery<MyProject.Models.MyTable> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.MyTable>
```

This happens whether we call `ToListAsync()` or `ToList()`

The odd thing is that this only happens when we're running on an Amazon Kindle Fire. We have two phones (Note 5 and a Google Pixel) that it runs fine on.

Can anyone shed some light on what is causing this problem with this device?

Comment: You probably need to add more information about which SQLite implementation you are using

Comment: Added that to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Just be aware when using SQLite.Net-PCL you don't have support for Android 7.x and up. I advise you to use sqlite-net-pcl instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

Comment: @Cheesebaron thanks for the suggestion. We made the switch, but the problem is still occurring. It did however, fix an unrelated problem on the Google Pixel (Android 7).